# Декоратор property: в наследовании не работает setter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Использую python-3.6.1

Потестировал свойства в наследовании, но оказалось, что сеттеры не работают.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, number):
        сам.__number = number

    @property
    def number(self):
        return сам.__number

    @number.setter
    def number(self, new: int):
        сам.__number = new


class MyClass2(MyClass):

    @property
    def number(self):
        return super().number + 1

    @number.setter
    def number(self, new: int):
        super().number = new


class MyClass3(MyClass2):

    @property
    def number(self):
        return super().number + 1

    @number.setter
    def number(self, new: int):
        super().number = new


i = MyClass3(0)  # ок
print(i.number)  # -> 2 То есть в каждом геттере добавлено по единичке.
i.number = 10  # AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'number'
```

По идее сеттер должен работать.

Почему так происходит - геттер работает, а сеттер нет?

Стоит ли использовать свойства в питоне, раз их нельзя мутировать?
В каких случаях?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как следует использовать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021464/how-to-call-a-property-of-the-base-class-if-this-property-is-being-overwritten-i)

Почему так происходит [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810369/python-super-and-setting-parent-class-property)

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.__number = number

    @property
    def number(self):
        return self.__number

    @number.setter
    def number(self, new: int):
        self.__number = new


class MyClass2(MyClass):
    @property
    def number(self):
        return MyClass.number.fget(self) + 1

    @number.setter
    def number(self, new: int):
        super(MyClass2, self.__class__).number.fset(self, new)


class MyClass3(MyClass2):
    @property
    def number(self):
        return MyClass2.number.fget(self) + 1

    @number.setter
    def number(self, new: int):
        super(MyClass3, self.__class__).number.fset(self, new)
```

Использовать вместо `self` - `сам` - дурной тон

Comment: Не нашёл где написано почему так происходит.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue14965

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595607/using-super-in-a-propertys-setter-method-when-using-the-property-decorator-r?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: спасибо за ссылочки.

Comment: изврат с геттерами такой не нужен. Можно через супер обращаться, нормально. А вот с сеттерами подход работает. Причём не надо прописывать зависимость к суперклассу.